# PhpStorm Deployment menu missing on Mac OS X

Tags: php, deployment, phpstorm

I'm working in PhpStorm 2016.1, on Mac OS X. Colleagues who are on Windows have in Tools tab a Deployment menu. I've got nothing...

Same in `Preferences > Build, Execution & Deployment` -- all I've got is Debugger and Coverage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that **"Remote Hosts Access" plugin** is enabled in `Settings/Preferences | Plugins`.

That's the only reason why "Deployment" menu would not be available to you.

---

**UPDATE 2021-04-13:**

From 2020.x version the plugin is now called **"FTP/SFTP Connectivity (ex. Remote Hosts Access)"**

Comment: Thanks, you're a life saver. i don't understand why on mac it's not activated by default. but thanks !

Comment: It's either some glitch .. or you did not noticed how you disabled it yourself. When installed, ALL plugins are activated by default.

Comment: I just had this plugin disable itself after windows froze and a hard boot was required. Perhaps an invalidated cache file somewhere? Regardless, I simply enabled the plugin again and now it works.

Comment: For no obvious reason - the plugin got disabled on my Mac/PHPStorm today (I'm heavily relying on it, so it couldn't go unnoticed) after working for years. Renabling helped.